# How to get more than 255 columns in an excel sheet using Apache POI 3.6

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm creating a calendar in excel. Column 1 is 01.01.2010 (dd.MM.yyyy), Column 2 is 02.01.2010 and so on.

This is my code:

```
int day_cell = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++)
{
     Date day = days.get(i);

     HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(day_cell++);
     cell.setCellValue(day.toString());
}
```

When I get to column 256 POI throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column index (256).  Allowable column range for BIFF8 is (0..255) or ('A'..'IV')
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.checkBounds(HSSFCell.java:926)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.<init>(HSSFCell.java:162)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.createCell(HSSFRow.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.createCell(HSSFRow.java:119)
```

I found this bug-report suggesting it was fixed in the 3.6 release. We were using 3.5 but changing to 3.6 doesn't seem to do any good. Anyone got any tips?

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46806

Edit: Seems like the bug-issue was about formulas..

Comment: I'm not looking to change to any other API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to switch from the **org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel**  to the **org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel**

This allows you to use 16k columns or something like that.

Comment: Answer by @kk1010 offers a better explanation of the "why".

Answer (score 28):

Pre-2007 excel sheets had a limitation of 256 columns. Those sheets also generate ".xls" extension. Excel 2007 and onwards can accommodate 16K columns, are based on an XML format and generate ".xlsx" format.
The POI object model for pre-2007 sheets is `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel` while the object model for 2007 onwards sheets is `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel`
The package `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel` provides a uniform interface covering both the object models. So to create more than 256 columns, you will have to use classes within the `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel` package or within `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel`.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem may be with Excel, not your API.

[The maximum number of columns in a pre-Excel 2007 spreadsheet is 256](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA101375451033.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You might consider switching from portrait to landscape (in other words, transposing the data) so that you get to use 65k rows for days of the year. This is exactly what I did with a report requiring a large number of columns and small number of rows.

Alternatively, you might split the year in 6-month sub periods, each one on its own sheet.

These are both stopgap solutions, but might provide you with a "good enough" solution, depending on the requirements you have.

Answer (score 2):

That's because Excel has limited number columns
See this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx

Comment: So there's no way you can have more than 255 characters in Excel? I can manually input more than 255; how is the limit 255 set then?

Answer (score 2):

How to get more than 255 columns in an excel sheet using Apache POI
try

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>`enter code here`
   <version>3.15</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.15</version>
  </dependency>
```