# Reading more than 255 characters from excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to read a sheet data from excel (tried both oldedb and odbc)  and found out that there is 255 characters limit. 
I tried using `Range` object as suggested in other threads

```
(SELECT * FROM [ref_MethodInput$A1:S362])
```

but still no luck. So apart from using interop is there any other way to overcome this? Registry edit is also not advisable as that would need registry edits in all client machines.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is with the Jet Provider, why not try the Microsoft Excel Driver listed under ODBC connctions.

[Source](http://forums.asp.net/t/1349022.aspx)

Comment: i am doing this from my C# application. Could you pls provide a link/example on how how i go about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488404/excel-unable-to-insert-more-than-255-chars

Comment: thanks for the links. i adapted connection string from there but still it fails . The long string is on 101 line                                         OleDbConnection excelcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=200';");

Answer (score 0):

below code work for me.
import data from excel (.xls & .xlsx) file (work for column value more than 255 character).

```
using Excel;

        try
        {
            FileStream stream = File.Open(strFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            IExcelDataReader excelReader = null;
            if (extension.Trim() == ".xls")
            {
                excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            }
            else if (extension.Trim() == ".xlsx")
            {
                excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            }
            excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

            excelReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            mResult.Message = err.Message;
        }
```

Download nuget packages:
 1) PCLStorage (Version: 1.0.2)
 2) ExcelDataReader-DevNet45 (version: 1.0.0.2)

[Code reference](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=exceldatareader)