# How to avoid 'Allowable column range for BIFF8 is (0..255) or ('A'..'IV')' error during export to Excel format using JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

During export report as *Excel* sheet via *JRXlsExporter* I got the error: `Invalid column index (256).  Allowable column range for BIFF8 is (0..255) or ('A'..'IV')`. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

*JasperReports* is using *Apache POI* library for exporting reports to *MS Excel* format.

The engine has several exporters for proceeding export to *MS Excel* format:

- *[JRXlsExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsExporter.html)* - generates output as *xls* file
- *[JRXlsxExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRXlsxExporter.html)* - generates output as *xlsx* file

The old versions of *MS Excel* have limitation of using **less than 257** columns at workbook. The new versions (2007+) have the new limitation:  **16 384** columns.

The *JRXlsxExporter* uses the API (based on *XSSF*) that allow to export report in a new format (*.xlsx*). The *JRXlsExporter* is using *HSSF* implementation of *Apache POI*.

To avoid this error it is enough to use *[JRXlsxExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/ooxml/JRXlsxExporter.html)*.

---

More info:

- [POI-HSSF and POI-XSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) - common description of two approaches
- [How to get more than 255 columns in an excel sheet using Apache POI 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2326668/876298) - nice post about columns limitations